# Hide completed tasks in task list

Tags: view, tasks, task-list

When I (or anyone else) mark the check-box to indicate a task in the Task List is completed, the task is crossed out. However, the completed task still stays in the All Items view. How do I hide these so that I just see them in the default Completed view and not in the All Items view?

Comment: Any news on this?
I have the same issue.
Once a filter is applied there is no longer the ability to add sub-tasks.
As you can imagine, it becomes difficult to navigate once you have so many completed items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to edit the view and filter completed tasks. It can be confusing because there isn't an intuitive value to filter for the Completed column.

1. Open the view menu and click Modify this view.
2. Scroll down and expand the Filter option (if not already expanded).
3. Select Show items only when the following is true:
4. Specify the following criteria:

   - Column: Completed
   - Operator: is equal to
   - Value: No
5. Save your changes.

Completed items will still show until the page is refreshed, but then they will be filtered out of the view.

Comment: To add the answer, its better to create a new list from the existing default view and the apply the filter. And if required you can make the new task list view as default.

Comment: I agree with bkk that a new view is preferable and would be a better practice. Reference the steps to hide completed tasks, but best to do so in a new view set to default so that you still have a View All view

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this solution is that once you filter the view this way then you are unable to create subtasks and move them around because the view is now filtered which is extremely frustrating.  Right now I'm trying to work on a way to hide any items that are completed with JQuery to clean that list up and still make it functional.

Answer (score 0):

Open the view menu and click Modify this view.

Filter:

> Show items only when the following is true:

Specify the following criteria:
Column: Status
Operator: is not equal to
Value: Completed

Save your changes.
Completed items will still show until the page is refreshed, but then they will be filtered out of the view.